# Change line height in R console

Tags: r, ascii-art

Playing a bit with [ascii art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), in R, I'm wondering whether line height could be changed in the console.

In other words, and in the example below, I would like to remove blank between lines of black squares below:

```
cat(rep(c(rep("█", 50), "\n"), 5), sep="")
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
```

Any idea or pointer for "forget about it"?

Comment: It's a curious experiment that I've considered at times myself. My guess is that it is sensitive to the actual font in use, as well as the interface. Is this RStudio, `Rterm`, `R` on a terminal, or `R` on Emacs/ESS?

Comment: Ideally I would like it to work no matter the interface yet if I had to pick one I'd say, the RStudio console (that smells like the regular R console to me).